# Max lines of soap request in web_service_call function

Tags: loadrunner

We have 10000 lines of soap request which needs to be passed in web_service_call function.

What is the maximum size/lines of request that we can send using web_service_call?

Which method is the best option for sending 10000 lines of SOAP request?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.... see what happens.

Experimentation should provide the answer quite quickly.  Use those testing skills!

Example:

```
10K    No
5K     Yes
7.5K   Yes
8.75K  No
8.125K Yes
8.44K  Yes
8.6K   No
8.52K  No
8.48K  Yes
8.5K   Yes  - Hypothetical limit in example
```